# What format should the channel name be for Flutter platform channels?

Tags: android, flutter, platform

I'm adding creating my own Platform Channel (specifically, Method Channel for Android) and following https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-1-create-a-new-app-project

I see:

> All channel names used in a single app must be unique; we recommend
>   prefixing the channel name with a unique ‘domain prefix’, e.g.
>   samples.flutter.io/battery.

Does the name need to be a specific format? E.g. Can I name my channel just plain ol' `battery`? Or does it have be something around the format `my_company.flutter.io/battery`? Or something else? I've tried all sorts of Strings but each time I'm getting a:

`MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getBattery on channel battery)`

So I'm wondering if maybe my channel name format is incorrect.
I think my method name getBattery is correct. But to clarify, I want to do:

```
final result = await platform.invokeMethod('getBattery');
```

not with the plugin prefix, right?:

```
final result = await platform.invokeMethod('battery.getBattery');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got a live example [here](https://github.com/shadowsheep1/flutter_app_000001) I've done some times ago.

> Does the name need to be a specific format? E.g. Can I name my channel
>   just plain ol' battery? Or does it have be something around the format
>   my_company.flutter.io/battery? Or something else?

As the channel name must be unique, the good practice is to prefix it with your `bundle(iOS)/package(Android) id`.

So for example:

```
static const platform =
      const MethodChannel('it.versionestabile.flutterapp000001/pdfViewer');
```

Anyway you can call it wathever you want but it should be unique and equals on your Dart and Android/iOS side.

```
private static final String CHANNEL = "it.versionestabile.flutterapp000001/pdfViewer";
```

But "calling" it it's like putting inside the channel, something.

Because the channel is **a channel** (imagine a pipe) and what you put inside it to be pass throught it from on side (Dart) to another (Android/iOS) is totally another tale ^_^.

And what you put inside it, it should be catch equal from the other side.

```
platform.invokeMethod('viewPdf', args);
```

So what you are sending through channels are simply **messages**.

*You put bottle with a letter inside the pipe ^_^*

Now you have to catch this message on your native code side like `'viewPdf'`.

```
new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if (call.method.equals("viewPdf")) {
                  if (call.hasArgument("url")) {
                    String url = call.argument("url");
                    File file = new File(url);
                    //*
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            file);
                            //*/
                    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    target.setDataAndType(photoURI,"application/pdf");
                    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(target);
                    result.success(null);
                  }
                } else {
                  result.notImplemented();
                }
              }
            });
  }
```

Otherwise you'll get trapped in

```
} else {
   result.notImplemented();
}
```

If you have followed the example you should have this, on your Android native code side:

```
@Override
public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {
        int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();

        if (batteryLevel != -1) {
            result.success(batteryLevel);
        } else {
            result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
        }
    } else {
        result.notImplemented();
    }
}
```

So you should call:

```
platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel');
```

Because the code of the example it's expecting a message `'getBatteryLevel'` to be passed through the channel.

**Strengthening up concepts**

So just to strengthen up all these concepts in mind I'll go further telling you that you can decide to use a channel to serve a single operation or to serve multiple operation. The choice is up to you.

So you could have

*Dart side:*

```
  static const singleChannel =
      const MethodChannel('it.versionestabile.flutterapp000001/single');
  static const multiChannel =
      const MethodChannel('it.versionestabile.flutterapp000001/multi');
```

*Native side (Android):*

```
  private static final String SINGLE_CHANNEL = "it.versionestabile.flutterapp000001/single";
  private static final String MULTI_CHANNEL = "it.versionestabile.flutterapp000001/multi";
```

And here some toy handlers:

```
new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), MULTI_CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
        new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
            if (call.method.equals("op1")) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                      .setTitle(call.method)
                      .setMessage("I'm the " + call.method + " of the by design multi operation channel!")
                      .create()
                      .show();
            } else if (call.method.equals("op2")) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(call.method)
                        .setMessage("I'm the " + call.method + " of the by design multi operation channel!")
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        });

new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), SINGLE_CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
        new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
            if (call.method.equals("hello")) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                      .setTitle("hello!")
                      .setMessage("I'm the by design single operation channel!")
                      .create()
                      .show();
            } else {
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        });
```

[image]

```
  void _invokeMultiChannelOp2() {
    multiChannel.invokeMethod('op2');
  }

  void _invokeMultiChannelOp1() {
    multiChannel.invokeMethod('op1');
  }

  void _invokeSingleChannel() {
    singleChannel.invokeMethod('hello');
  }

floatingActionButton: SafeArea(
    child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.library_music),
                onPressed: _invokeMultiChannelOp1),
            new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.note),
                onPressed: _invokeMultiChannelOp2),
            new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.plus_one),
                onPressed: _invokeSingleChannel),
          ],
        )),
  ),
```